# ¿Cómo tener diferentes sesiones en el mismo dominio?

Tags: php

En la escuela tenemos un servidor PHP donde cada alumno tiene un subdirectorio y en cada subdirectorio tenemos la portada de cada alumno.

Cada alumno tiene acceso por FTP a su propio directorio, y nada más.

Mi pregunta es:

Si yo defino `$_SESSION["id"]` **en mi directorio**, ¿otro alumno desde su directorio podría recuperar la variable que yo definí?

Tengo entendido que las sesiones son para todo el dominio, por lo tanto, si otro alumno quisiera saber mis credenciales, le bastaría con tener un script que cuando uno entrara a su página, guardara todo lo de está en la variable `$_SESSION[]` en un archivo de texto/base de datos.

Si es así, ¿se puede solucionar?.

Comment: Voy a agregar información importante en mi respuesta ahora que he leído con detenimiento algunos aspectos de la pregunta que había leído entre líneas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondo a las tres preguntas que planteas y agrego un apéndice extra con consejos de seguridad.

---

**Si yo defino $_SESSION["id"] en mi directorio, ¿otro alumno desde su directorio podría recuperar la variable que yo definí?**

Así es. Por defecto la ruta de la cookie es el directorio raíz, por lo que todos los subdirectorios recibirán la misma cookie con el mismo valor.

---

**Si yo defino `$_SESSION["id"]` *en mi directorio*, ¿otro alumno desde su directorio podría recuperar la variable que yo definí?**

Así es. Como el contenido de la cookie es (por defecto) el nombre de un archivo en el que se almacenan las variables de sesión, el contenido de las variables de sesión será compartido por todos los directorios.

---

**Si es así, ¿se puede solucionar?**

Debes modificar la ruta de la cookie antes de llamar a [`session_start()`](https://php.net/es/session-start) y, además, podrías cambiar el nombre de la cookie.

Puedes modificar el valor [`session.cookie_path`](https://php.net/es/session.configuration#ini.session.cookie-path) (ruta de la cook)ie y [`session.name`](https://php.net/es/session.configuration#ini.session.name) (nombre de la cookie) usando [`ini_set()`](https://php.net/es/ini-set):

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/ruta');
ini_set('session.name', 'nombre_de_mi_cookie');
session_start();
```

También puedes hacer uso de [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://php.net/es/session-set-cookie-params) y [`session_name()`](https://php.net/es/function.session-name) para conseguir los mismos resultados:

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params($duracion, '/ruta', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
session_name('nombre_de_mi_cookie');
session_start();
```

Recuerda hacerlo **antes** de llamar a [`session_start()`](https://php.net/es/session-start) en **todas** las páginas PHP en las que uses el sistema de sesiones.

---

**NOTA IMPORTANTE DE SEGURIDAD**

**NUNCA**, repito, **NUNCA** almacenes credenciales en variables de sesión. Se guardan en archivos en la máquina del servidor y podrían ser accedidos por terceras personas.

Existen miles de alternativas a almacenar credenciales en las variables de sesión. Depende de tu caso podría bastar con almacenar el identificador del usuario que iniciado sesión.